# Tail Recursion in Programming Erlang 2nd edition by Joe Armstrong

Tags: erlang, tail-recursion

In Joe Armstrong's book, at the end of chapter 12.7 he says:

"Avoiding this is easy; if you write a function F that never returns (such as loop()), make sure you never call anything ​after​ calling F, and don’t use F in a list or tuple constructor."

Excerpt From: Joe Armstrong. "Programming Erlang, Second Edition."

What does he mean by: "and don’t use F in a list or tuple constructor."

Thanks

Comment: Please, give us some more context. I don't have the book in front of me. What is it that you are trying to avoid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the book, but literally it means that you must avoid the following situations:

```
loop() ->
    receive
        M -> do_stuff()
    end,
    loop()
end.

some_func() ->
    foo(),
    loop(),
    % Don't do this
    bar() % bar will never be called
end.

other_func() ->
    % Don't do this
    T = {test,loop()}, % T will never be created
    % Nor this
    L = [loop()|lists:seq(1,12)]
end.
```

Note: This has nothing to do with the tail recursion mentioned in the question's title. The function loop/0 is tail recursive in this example.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. I think he means don't do this:

loop() ->
    receive
        M -> do_stuff()
    end,
    [loop()|lists:seq(1,12)]
end.